# Stringの改行コードがブラウザで改行されない。

Tags: html5

Springboot MVCを勉強しています。
index.htmlをHTML5で用意し、コントローラークラスをjavaで用意しました。
■コントローラクラス

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav) {
    mav.setViewName("index");
    String test = "TEST A\nTEST B";
    mav.addObject("test",test);
    return mav;
}
```

■index.html

```
<p th:text="${test}"></p>
```

とすると表示はされるのですが一切改行されません。
改行コード違いかしらと「\r\n」でも試してみたのですがされませんでした…。

ブラウザで表示する場合改行コードは違うのでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLブラウザでは通常空白文字（スペースや改行）は単に1つのスペースとして表示されます。
改行したい部分には[brタグ](http://www.htmq.com/html/br.shtml)を用います。
例：`<br />`

スペースや改行をそのままにしたい場合には、その全体を[preタグ](http://www.htmq.com/html/pre.shtml)で囲みます。
例：`<pre>この中の部分では空白文字  はそのまま使われる</pre>`

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！早速preタグを使用してみました。改行はされましたが、フォントなどがかわってしまいました。もとの文章を解析して、改行があればbrタグを追加する、みたいにしたほうがいいのかもしれません…

Comment: preタグでスタイル（フォントが固定幅フォントが使われる）が変わってしまうのが問題の場合はCSSでスタイルを指定すればいいような気がします。